# How do I know if I reached the limit of 1000 reputation points on suggested edits?

Tags: support, reputation, suggested-edits

Is there any way to check if you have reached the 1000 point reputation limit on suggested edits? Do you get a notification or do we have to manually calculate it?

Comment: You know you've reached it when you stop getting reputation from approved edits. =)

Comment: @AnnaLear - That encouragement is like promoting users to continue editing even when they do not till where they have reached. :D. But on the other side I feel such a promotion is not really necessary because other or new users should be given chance to improve their reputation especially when they have a question that has not been answered or received attention so that they can earn enough to place a bounty on it.

Comment: @JavierBrooklyn - We should not suggest edits for improving our reputation. But we should suggest edits to improve posts.

Comment: @AnnaLear - If it was to improve posts alone then there would have been widespread demand for suggesting edits than answering questions. Which is why stackoverflow kept a limit so that new users can do some work which does not pay them too high also and just enough to promote their valuable questions.

Comment: @JavierBrooklyn - Not Anna Lear but I replied you. There is limit on gaining reputation from suggested edit not on suggesting edits. User can suggest edits even after reaching 1000 limit (and up to 2000 over all)

Comment: @hims056 - Oh sorry I '@'ed the wrong person. Yes I have understood that there is a limit on gaining reputation alone and not on suggesting edits. But unless, you are given an incentive to make suggested edits, don't you think by continuing edits you are taking away the gain of another user who could have edited, because he has not used up the 1000 reputation limit? Its like you are making edits for no greater gain and other users are denied the gain. Its for that reason stackoverflow indirectly wants us to stop editing once you have received 1000 reputation from edits.

Comment: @JavierBrooklyn - There are [lots of users](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all) who edits thousands of posts. But still there are *unlimited* chance for new users to suggest edits. Because [over 6500 questions are posted per day on SO](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#questionsperday)

Comment: @hims056 - Yes of course there is lot of chance and that chance is currently still available only because of the 1000 point reputation. If the limit wasn't there, not a single post would have been left to edit at any point of time. That is the difference, that the 1000 point limit makes. So as long as you have no loss, you can edit beyond 1000 reputation limit, no problem for that. But the fact is there are only a few users like maybe you who would do that, out of freewill and of course that is respected.

Answer (score 8):

Go to `sitename.com/reputation`. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

You will find there (at the end of the page):

> earned XXXX reputation from suggested edits

Comment: This is somewhat informal on the side of stackoverflow and it would be good if the suggested edits statistic is made visible under reputation in profile -  http://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/xxxx?tab=reputation

Comment: @JavierBrooklyn - Sure you can add the new feature request for that.

Comment: @Javier - I don't think the info is important to most people, because they will reach 2000 rep way before editing 500 posts. For example, I only ever got 72 points from suggested edits (and have performed the next 3000 edits free of charge). The rep is just a bonus to get you started.

Comment: Statistics not just for suggested edits alone that stackoverflow could provide (although atleast for me suggested edits was more important) but also for Reputation from votes, chosen answers etc. all separately.