# Reputation has freezed for quite some time

Tags: support, reputation, suggested-edits

It seems my reputation is not increasing even after I did some edits on some questions and answers recently.

I don't see any increase in my reputation even after the edits that were proposed and approved.

**Here's my reputation tab**:

[image: rep]

**Here's my latest activity** *(suggestions I made)*:

[image: sugg]

Is it likely to be solved recently? Or, is it just occurring with me?

Comment: Is it possible that you've maxed out your suggested edit rep? You can only earn 1K rep from suggested edits. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work/76284#76284) for info.

Comment: @Catija Thanks, that might be it :) 
I believe, I have more than 500 suggestion till date http://stackoverflow.com/users/6290553/rakiti%C4%87?tab=activity and seems to have met the **total rep cap limit on edits** :)

Comment: @Rakitić see [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167801/152859) for a way to verify for certain that is indeed the case.